# Copying files in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: copy

I am new to Ubuntu. I am wondering how to copy files in terminal.

Source location 
`/home/Drive_1/file_1.txt`

To be copied at 
`/home/Drive_2/`

I am already inside Drive_1 and trying

`cp file_1.txt /Drive_2`

but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both directories are in the same parent directory you should not put a `/` but a `../`in fron of the directory to copy

```
# we are in /home/Drive_1
cp file_1.txt ../Drive_2
```

Your command is interpreted as

> copy file to root/directory

not

> copy file to /home/directory/Drive_2

Answer (score 2):

`/Drive_2`specifies a path starting at root.

`/Home/Drive_2`is already more appropriate but I guess you will mean `/home/<your userid>/Drive_2` where, of course, you have to replace `<userid>` by the appropriate mention.

Another possibility if `Drive_2`is a subdirectory of your curent directory is `../Drive_2` where `..` stands for the parent of the current directory.